# Adding the word "that" to maintain symmetry in sentences

Tags: style, creative-writing

Example from my own writing:

> He wouldn't have guessed **(that)** there
>   would be someone with diarrhea in the toilet. Or **that** the ferry's rail
>   would be half his size. Or **that** the night would become dark,
>   windy and rainy, making it impossible for the ferry's crew to find him
>   in the water."

I think the first *that* is unnecessary. But adding it would make it symmetrical to the other sentences. Is this something that writers usually do? Or I should just omit that first *that*?

Answer (score 4):

I agree with both your points: if your first sentence stood alone, I'd omit *that*. But in sequence with the other two, it sounds better to leave it in.

There is an actual rule in English linguistics called *that-deletion,* which allows you to drop the word "that" before certain independent clauses if you choose to. In this case, I'd keep it.